# How to find accommodation on a multi-island trip to the Azores?

Tags: accommodation, portugal, azores

The Azores seems like a very interesting place to do. Most planes arrive at Ponta Delgada, but from there every Azores portal advises to do a multi-island journey.
There are a multitude of companies offering these trips, but all seem to offer full package trips. I am just not the "full-package" kind of traveler. I would really like to do a multi-island trip in the Azores, but decide on a day-to-day basis when to change island.

Is this feasible in the Azores? Can I find B&B or self-catering accommodation on arrival?

Answer (score 8):

7 years ago I've been to all 5 islands in Central Group for my honeymoon, with nothing arranged except the flying ticket to Angra do Heroísmo in Terceira. I stayed 2 days in each island. It was easy to travel between the islands, whether by plane (SATA) or by boat. Also found nice places to stay, even in small Graciosa. We rented a car in Terceira, from there on we rented bikes.

I also like to travel by my own with a basic plan. But this was my honeymoon, so it should be perfect! Well, it was, a perfect match of adventure, nature and romance ;)